# Kexec on embeded images

Tags: bootloader

I'm trying to boot my kernel image (bzImage format and  which is built using buildroot) with kexec. This bzImage got its embedded initrd too. But when I try kexec, it just hangs. I'm not sure where I can see kexec logs.

[root@localhost boot]# kexec -v
kexec-tools-testing 20070330 released 30th March 2007

[root@localhost boot]# kexec -l /boot/bzImage -d --command-line=quiet noapic ro noswap
setup_linux_vesafb: 800x600x16 @ f0000000 +1d4c00

[root@localhost boot]# kexec -e

Older kexec binary clearly mentions in help that it doesn't support bzImage yet but newer ones do support it. So I in fact tried all kexec versions (2.0.0/1/2/3 and some test versions too). But I get same result. I'm trying kexec from Centos 5.5 32 bit and bzImage is built for i386. This is actually VM on Xenserver but I don't think that should matter anyway. Interestingly if I install my bzImage locally with grub.conf (and using same cmdline above), it boots fine with bootloader. So image seems to be fine.

I'm pretty new to Linux boot stuff so probably missing something very obvious here. Any help or pointers provided will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what played magic here but upgrading busybox package inside kernel image (through buildroot) helped. It started booting fine with all kexec versions. There's one problem which I see is console of box is garbeled for some reason (post kexec) but if I ssh to box it shows everything fine.